# Proportions are telling a different story than odds ratios

Tags: regression, proportion, odds-ratio, odds

**Context**

- Stimuli: 2 different designs (A, B)
- Outcome: task success (binary y/n)
- n = 100
- Between-subjects (50 Design A; 50 design B)

**Interpreting the proportions suggests there is no real difference in success b/t designs**

- Error bars are largely overlapping.
- Design A has an 80% success rate
- Design B has an 75% success rate
- chi-squared test (example below) suggests that success isn't contingent on design.
  E.g.,
    Prop.test(c(80,75),c(20,25))

**I do a logistic regression, which suggests the odds ratios, however, are significantly different. This suggests that I should generalize Design A has a significantly greater odds of success vs. non-success than Design B**

- I get an odds ratio of 1.33, suggesting Design A has 1.33x better odds at bringing success vs. non-success than Design B.
- The 95% CI is large, suggesting a good deal of uncertainty, but it doesn't include 1.
- Sample size is low, but based on what I've garnered, 100 people and 1 predictor variable is okay for logistic regression.

**dilemma**: these are two contradictory interpretations. I cannot seem to reconcile them. Should I choose one? How would I justify this choice?

*Growing hunches*: 
Feels like my confusion is on the conceptual distinction between odds and proportions. I feel like since odds are derived from the proportions they should tell a similar story.

Comment: I think you've perhaps misinterpreted a couple of things.  First, "Error bars are largely overlapping" can happen even with statistically significant differences.  Second, the odds ratio of 1.33 in favor of A is little more than observing that the ratio of successes to failures for A is 4-1  and for B is 3-1, and the ratio of (4/1) to (3/1) is 1.33.  It doesn't mean the chance of success (75% or 80%) is 1.33x, it means the odds of success (4-1 or 3-1) is 1.33x.  At the end of the day, I'd be choosing to rely on that 95% CI that doesn't include 1, at least if I couldn't do more analysis.

Comment: @jbowman thanks for the great answer! Could I push a bit further now that you've helped zone in on my confusion? I do a chi-squared test and find that success does not seem to be contingent upon design. I'm thinking, "okay, well the design doesn't seem to be a clear winner at this preliminary stage, more analysis should go down before i say the new design has changed nothing in terms of this outcome."  Then, because I'm curious, I run the logistic regression and finds that actually, the odds of success are higher in Design A. How do I avoid **feeling** this is contradictory?

Comment: The chi-square test isn't going to be as powerful as the logistic regression for this data, so I wouldn't be too concerned about the contradiction.  I suspect your logistic regression p-value was not all that extreme, so it's entirely plausible that a different test would come to a different conclusion, especially one that is less powerful.  Also, "The Difference Between “Significant” and “Not Significant” is not Itself Statistically Significant", as  Andrew Gelman and Hal Stern wrote in The American Statistician some years ago.